# call a method through string dynamically

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I have a number of methods like
this.UIMap.FirstName,this.UIMap.LastName,this.UIMap.Email, etc.. etc.. in my coded UI designer.
Each of the fields in the page have one method in designer.
I am preparing a framework like, the field name is taken from excel, the corresponding method should be executed and the result should be written across the field name in the final STATUS column of the excel.

Am i making myself clear ? :)
If so , how do i make a call to such a method.
I have written something like this :

```
    string fieldname = WorkSheet.Cells[i, 2].Value;                         
    UIMap uimap = new UIMap();
    Type thisType = typeof(UIMap);
    thisType.InvokeMember(fieldname , BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public,
 null, uimap,null);
```

But it is throwing error as :

Test method SampleDemo.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1 threw exception: 
System.MissingMethodException: Method 'SampleDemo.UIMap.FirstName1' not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your FirstName is a function or it just a property?if it's a property so you can get value from it not call a method by reflection

```
typeof(UIMap).GetProperty("FirstName").GetValue(this.UIMap)
```

code like this

Comment: anyway, i have almost got half of it.. "SampleDemo.UIMap.FirstName1" i s being called.. i want the designer to be called instead of SampleDemo.. any suggestions?

Comment: Adding BindingFlags.Instance should solve the problem but I guess you've already got that covered. The UIMap is a partial class, one half of it comes from the UIMap.Designer.cs which is generated from the UIMap.uitest. So I'd say your codes is calling the right methods.

Comment: you exception is xxx.FirstName1 not found，and your method is?FirstName or FirstName1,maybe you excel data not same as the mehtod name

Comment: @kida:yes, the method called is right.. It is "SampleDemo.UIMap.FirstName1".. but still the error is thrown..
if we call it as this.UIMap.FirstName1, the method is called

Comment: MissingMethodException? Did you add the Instance flag? Like this: typeof(UIMap).InvokeMember("FirstName1", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, UIMap, null);
Or typeof(UIMap).GetMethod("FirstName1").Invoke(UIMap, null);